# How to use Mate-Panel in Gnome-Fallback Mode

Tags: gnome-classic, mate

Is it possible to run mate-panel inside gnome-fallback mode? Unity is annoying and gnome-fallback is not real gnome 2, so it would be nice if I could combine mate and gnome-fallback.

Comment: while in fallback mode, can you not just open a terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+t`) and type `mate-panel`? If so then you could add it to your startup applications. This does beg the question.... Why not just use the Mate session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have much luck adding gnome applets to the mate panel, here is what I'm using, on a mate-panel 1.4.0:

Left panel

- a few launchers
- Show Desktop Button 1.4.0
- CPU Frequency Scaling Monitor 1.4.0
- MATE Sensors Applet 1.2.0
- System Monitor 1.4.0
- Shut down button (not sure what flavor/version)

Bottom panel

- mintmenu 5.3.8
- Window List 1.4.0
- Notification Area 1.4.0
- Main Menu (another menu icon from MATE, it doesn't have an about box)
- Weather Report 1.4.0
- Workspace Switcher 1.4.0

The mate-panel is from the mate-desktop.org repositories, mintmenu is installed locally, and Ubuntu version is from raring 13.04 repositories. Themes are from webupd8team ppa's.

I mainly use mate-session configured with compiz, although you can launch mate-panel in a gnome-session in either Unity or Gnome shell.

Comment: I only need "indicator applet complete" but he is in mess on mate-panel, so for now I'll stick with gnome-fallback panel. Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to see for yourself you’d type mate-panel in the terminal and see how it works for you, but I don't know anybody who did an integration job between them. I ran it in all three environments, gnome-shell, gnome-fallback and unity, and you can use many mate applets in this panel, including mintmenu and window list, hardware temps, cpufreq, weather and more.
You may want to use themes designed to look the same for both gtk2 and gtk3, such as Faience, since you'll be using for example caja and nautilus side by side.
I personally like to use mate-panel with Compiz for the effects.

Comment: What applets do you use with mate-panel. I have put indicator applet complete (from gnome2 panel) but indicator was in mess, for example, user name was on left and calendar was on right.